# Jquery duplicate selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a search page that uses a form and checkboxes to display results. When the page reloads with the new results, I want to display something like this at the top of the page so users can easily remove one of their selections:

X Blue     X Red     X Black

My checkboxes look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_white" value="white">White
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_blue" value="blue" checked="checked">Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_red" value="red" checked="checked">Red
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_orange" value="orange">Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_purple" value="purple">Purple
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color_black" value="black" checked="checked">Black
```

How do I go about getting the selected checkboxes, and then duplicating them at the top of the page so a user can just click on the X to make it "uncheck?"

Click events and form submission is done in jquery, so I'm assuming that this can be done that way too. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: The only thing i've found is a jquery function called 'clone' but I could not get it to work. The examples I've seen are more along the lines of "checking" other values that exist on the page and not creating an exact duplicate of an existing checkbox. Maybe I'm googling for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a blank div at the top

```
<div id="checked"></div>
```

And then on load create a button for each checked input

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked')=='checked'){
            $('#checked').append('<input id="'+$(this).attr('id').substring(6)+'" type="button" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">')
        }
    }); 
    $('input').on('click',function(){
        var i='color_'+$(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+i).prop('checked','');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

If a button is clicked remove the check and remove itself.

Comment: Yay! This will work! Thank you very much!!! Will upvote when I get to 15 reputation. Thanks again for the help!